# Windows Phone 8 Music album Listing Issue

Tags: 8.0, xbox-music

I have a Nokia Lumia 1020 with Windows Phone 8.0.

I have thousands of songs grouped by album name in the Music folder, but in the music listing it's showing wrong.

For example, I have Album 1, Album 2, Album 3, Album 4 etc.

And in each album I have about 4 to 6 songs, e.g. Album 1 => song 1, song 2, song 3, etc.

In music listing it's showing like this:

> Album 1 => Song 1
>   Album 1 => Song 2
>   Album 1 => Song 3
>
> Album 2 => Song 1
>   Album 2 => Song 2
>   Album 2 => Song 3
>
> Album 3 => Song 1
>   Album 3 => Song 2
>   Album 3 => Song 3

I want the output to be like this:

> Album 1 => Song 1, Song 2, Song 3
>   Album 2 => Song 1, Song 2, Song 3
>   Album 3 => Song 1, Song 2, Song 3

**Edit**  : ScreenShot Added

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I assume that by "music listing" you mean the Collection view in the built-in Music app? Or something else?

Comment: @Indrek yes you are right i am using built in music app

Comment: Perhaps you could add a screen shot to illustrate what you're seeing, as the built in music app has a "albums" list?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I have added the screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot, it looks like you have a "Various Artists" type album (specifically, a [film soundtrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azhagiya_Tamil_Magan#Soundtrack)), where each track has a different artist.

The information that the Music app shows you is taken from embedded metadata called ID3 tags. Specifically, tracks are grouped together based on a field called "Album artist". In your case I think that field is different for each track, causing the Music app to believe they are different albums despite having the same name (a valid assumption, considering many artists have albums called "Greatest Hits", "Best Of" and such, and you don't want those grouped together).

What you'll need to do is edit the MP3 files on your PC (either using Windows Explorer or something like [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en)) and make sure that the tags are set up as follows:

- The **Album artist** field should be set to "Various Artists", or maybe "A. R. Rahman" (the composer for this particular album), or in general whatever artist you want the tracks to be grouped together under.
- The **Contributing artists** field should be set to the artist(s) that performed each individual track.

That should fix it. You'll of course need to re-copy the music to your phone. It's time-consuming, but in my experience having your music collection properly tagged is well worth it.

Comment: i have check it but the value for each and every album songs it has the album name in Album Artist field

Comment: @S.Varun And the artist names your screenshot shows are in the "Contributing artists" fields?

Comment: yes i think its in contributing artists

Comment: Did you check the music files on your phone or on your computer? Try re-copying the files to your phone, after making sure that the tags are correct on the computer.

Comment: i have checked it and tried re copying it but no use... what to do

Comment: Everything Indrek said and, in addition, check that the tags are in ID3v2.3 (*not* ID3v2.4). If the tags are in ID3v2.4 you'll notice that the song information is not properly displayed in windows explorer. You can rewrite the tags in ID3v2.3 using Mp3Tag (mentioned by Indrek as well).